# Insert a multidimendional-array in to mysql with pdo, wrong inputs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, multidimensional-array

i'm trying to insert an array that looks like:

```
$prices = array(
        array('event_id' => 1, 'event_price_type' => 5, 'event_price' => 5, 'event_price_currency_id' => 1, 'event_price_info' => 'aaaa'),
        array('event_id' => 1, 'event_price_type' => 8, 'event_price' => 7, 'event_price_currency_id' => 1, 'event_price_info' => 'bbbb'), 
        array('event_id' => 1, 'event_price_type' => 1, 'event_price' => 8, 'event_price_currency_id' => 1, 'event_price_info' => 'cccc')
    );

// trace($prices);
```

What I have so far is:

```
try{
            $this->dbh->beginTransaction();

            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO event_prices(event_id, price_type, price, price_currency_id, price_info) VALUES(:event_id, :event_price_type, :event_price, :event_price_currency_id, :event_price_info)");

            foreach($prices as $insertRow){
                // trace($insertRow);
               // now loop through each inner array to match binded values
               foreach($insertRow as $column => $value){
                    echo "COMLOM WAARDE: {$column}, VALUE: {$value}<br/>";
                  $stmt->bindParam(":{$column}", $value);
               }
            }
            // NOW DO EXECUTE
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dbh->commit();
}catch(PDOException $e){echo 'Error ! '.$e->getMessage();die();}
```

This will insert the follow in mysql:

```
event_id    price_type  price   price_currency_id   price_info
0   0   0   0   cccc
```

where it has to be:

```
1   5   5   1   aaaa
1   8   7   1   bbbb
1   1   8   1   cccc
```

How can i fixe it?
And is it a save soluction without allowing sql injections?

Comment: You posted [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25934091/) 3 hours prior. Why should I reopen this?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate I'm new here and made a mistake.